# Obtener Name de un input en php

Tags: php, html

¿Se puede obtener el `name` de un input que se a enviado por post a traves de php?

Ejemplo:

```
<form method="post" action="controller.php">
<input type="text" name="nombre" value="perro">
<input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dado que a través de `$_POST` lo que obtenemos es:

> Un array asociativo de variables pasadas al script actual...
>
> <sub>[`$_POST` en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php)</sub>

Y teniendo en cuenta que las llaves (keys) de ese array son los valores del atributo `name`, en el caso de que lo que pases por POST sea un formulario.

Entonces, si te interesan solamente las llaves, puedes valerte de `array_keys`, para obtenerlas, ya que esta función:

> Devuelve todas las claves de un array o un subconjunto de claves de un
>   array.
>
> <sub>[`array_keys` en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-keys.php)</sub>

Entonces:

```
$arrLlaves=array_keys($_POST);
```

Te creará un array solamente con cada valor de los atributos `name` de tu formulario. Para leerlos, has de hacerlo como se leen los arrays.

Por el contrario, si te interesan también los valores, puedes proceder como indica @Sr1871 en su respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicacion! muy ilustrativo y funciona al 100 !

Answer (score 5):

`$_POST` te trae un arreglo de todas las variables de esta forma `[{name} => {value}];`

Si quieres obtener el name solo tienes que hacer

```
foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
    echo $name; //en tu ejemplo name sería nombre y $value sería perro
}
```

Y obtendrás el valor del nombre del input

Comment: Muchas gracias me ilumino me funciona igual que el comentario de arriba gracias!